# Embedding webview to a cordova project?

Tags: cordova

I was trying to follow the documentation on apache cordova on how to embed webview to an android project. Here is the link  http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html . I was stuck at 4th point because i dont have a main.xml file. I am not sure if the documentation works for the android platform ina cordova project. If this doesnt help, where can i find documentation to embed webviews. I tried to lookup but no success so far.
Help is greatly appreciated.!

Comment: So, do you already have a cordova project setup? If so, you do not need to add a webview. The documentation you are referencing is for adding a cordova webview to an existing natively built android application.

Comment: Yes sir. I have setup the cordova project. SO you are saying there is no need of webview for cordova projects. If so, how do i access my app through web. I have no clear idea of what a webview is. It is confusing. could you please share your knowledge.

Comment: @user3869280 A `webview` in XCode is an Object that will display a website on the device's screen. For example Safari Mobile uses a webview or any other browser app that needs to display websites.  The link you posted is for native Android apps. I guess you are trying to build an cordova application with HTML/CSS/JS? If so, you won't need a webview (unless you are developing a browser app). The **index.html** file in the **www** folder is were you code has to go.

Comment: A cordova project is a native application that has a default view that is a webview. This is so that you can write html/css/js and have it run as a native application on a device. If you have a cordova project setup, there already is a webview and you dont have to do anything with it. Just go into the `www` folder of the project and start building your application with html/css/js.

Comment: OK. so now how to access my app on a mobile device that i already installed my app. Yes, i am working towards integrating this hybrid app with a webapp thats already developed. My app is a scan reader. so i want my app to be integrated on the browser as a button and when one clicks the scanner should start and readback the results to the browser. If you could steer me towards the right path, I will be really grateful. Thankyou

Comment: my answer may help point you in the right direction. Are you using the Cordova CLI to initialize a project?

Comment: yes. I used CLI to initialize the project. I put my apk file on tomcat inside ROOT and i can access the app through localhost url. It asks me to download. Its fine untill here. And now i tried to create a button and link a url to the button so it will ask me to download again but it isnt :(    I used this code in a jsp page.     <form action="http://localhost:8082/myFolder/Test-debug.apk">
        <input type="submit" value="ScanEngine">
    </form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [Dawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735920/dawson-loudon) has pointed out, a cordova application essentially is a webview

**What is a View**
A view is a native class which handles layout and interaction with the user. All mobile platforms have some form of this abstraction, and they are highly analogous. iOS has [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) and [UIWebview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), Android has [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and [Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) classes, Windows Phone 8 has [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser), etc. There are many many different types of view, each providing something different.

**What is a WebView**
A webview is a browser without the chrome (ui). That's pretty much it. It's a browser, it has a DOM, a js runtime. It can load URL's.

**What is Cordova Webview**
Cordova Webview is a subclass of the native android webview class, which enables cordova to do its magic. It has a variety of extra functionality to support the cordova api's (native-js communication bridge, plugins, etc). It's the container that your cordova app runs in.

**Why you probably don't need to worry too much about it**
Unless you want to mix the cordova webview with other native views (a rare and complex use case), you absolutely don't need to worry that your app even runs in a webview. It's just the container.

**initialize your project with the Cordova CLI**

```
$ cordova create BAZ && cd BAZ
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova run android
```

this will create a project, add the android platform, and run it. The HelloWorld app you should see on your device or emulator is the HelloWorld app in the www/ project directory running inside an Android webview.

Hope this helps!

- Lorin

Comment: thanks for the info. i have already done the steps following your guide lines. How do i access my app on a browser? is there any url that can lead me to open my app? My app is installed on my phone and runs successfully. now i want to open it when i click a button on browser.

Comment: Yeah! Your app will have it's own icon like any other app. However, you can open apps from the browser using Android intents! Check out this SO answer for how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent