# How to open an app from a link in android?

Tags: android

This question has been asked more then 10 times, for example :

1. [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)
2. [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)
3. [How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android)

I tried more then 10 links and tutorials and it seems like i'm missing something.

I do the following :

1. create a new android project you an empty action.
2. I then create the following Android manifest :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.my_test"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="18"
       android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>

           <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="http" android:host="planb.site11.com"/>
           </intent-filter>

           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
               <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" android:host="path" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```
3. Then i enter a small webpage i created, hoping on of the links will work (using google chrome on nexus 5)
   here is the page (his source is very simple)
   http://planb.site11.com/
4. and click on the links, but nothing opens my app :(

What am i missing ? 
How can i see in my android which apps are signed for which intents ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your second filter does not match anything on the Web page, as you are not using a host named `path` on the Web page. With respect to the first filter, not all browsers support this, as some assume that `http` links are ones they should handle themselves, without checking to see if there is an app on the device that is supposed to handle it.

Comment: Regarding the second filter, thanks, i edited it and now it works. regarding the first, so how come youtube opens when i search for youtube in google and press on "m.youtube.com" ? it is also an http link

Comment: Off the top of my head, I have no idea. In particular, I thought Chrome did handle those links properly, finding the app and offering a chooser.