# how can cordova open app from http or https url?

Tags: javascript, cordova, url-scheme

I found many answers for a custom URL-Scheme like this (`mycoolapp://somepath`).

[This plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme/blob/fbd7a00e04d4ec6d6166557d31e668f657673aba/README.md) for example adds a custom URL-Sheme.*

But I don't want a custom URL-Scheme, I want a "normal" URL like this (`http://www.mycoolapp.com/somepath`).

If you open this in you Browser or click on a Hyperlink for example, then it should ask you to open my app (like google maps does it).

This question maybe already has an answer, but i can't find it.

If you don't know what I mean, that's how it should look if you click on the link to my website on an Android Device:

[image: application link]

Just with my app to select.

Comment: have you tried using the http url as url-scheme?

Comment: @jcesarmobile wouldn't that mean (if it actually works) that **every** website would open my app?

Comment: I mean the whole website url h ttp://www.mycoolapp.com/, not just the http://. Some apple apps can be opened with a regular web url, but maybe they use some private API, I have not tested.

Comment: I think I want to do this ; so if they have my app it opens that, and if not it opens the website. Will it work like that for the EddyVerbruggen plugin linked to in this question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the same problem I've used existing [webintent](https://github.com/cordova-misc/cordova-webintent) plugin, modified the android manifest file - add those lines to activity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

and modified the index.html ondeviceready:

```
function deviceReady() {
    window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
        console.log("INTENT URL: " + url);
        //...
    }); 
}
```

**EDIT**

I've just noticed a behavior which may be unwanted. When you open the app using the link (intent) from another application, it will (in many cases) create a new instance and not use the already running one (tested with gmail and skype). To prevent this a solution is to change Android Launch mode in config.xml file:

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

(It works with cordova 3.5, not sure about the older version)

Then you need to add one more function to ondeviceready:

```
window.plugins.webintent.onNewIntent(function(url) {
    console.log("INTENT onNewIntent: " + url);
});
```

This one is triggered when the app was already running and was brought to front with intent.

Comment: i found out one small issue with the code, you should also add the onNewIntent and maybe change the LaunchMode, please take a look at the edit

Comment: This works really well without the need to install a plugin or set anything up. What would be the equivalent of this for the iOS?

Comment: Works fine when app is not launched, if launched in background it doesn't works, had to add window.plugins.webintent.onNewIntent

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called "Universal Links" on iOS and "Deep Linking" on Android.

And there is a Cordova plugin to handle that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Comment: The plugin is deprecated.

Comment: @SohrabTaee This fork works well https://github.com/e-imaxina/cordova-plugin-deeplinks

Comment: https://github.com/e-imaxina/cordova-plugin-deeplinks is now archived as well.z

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28182653/96), but modifying the AndroidManifest via config.xml, the following did the trick for me. Trying to match on `android:name` didn't work no matter which permutations I used.

```xml
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application/activity[@android:label='@string/activity_name']">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.mysite.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/whatever/path" />
            </intent-filter>
        </config-file>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is detect the device that is connecting to http://www.mycoolapp.com/somepath

If it is a mobile device then you can present them with a page with a link with your custom url scheme that opens your app. Or auto open the custom url of  the app if you want.

Comment: The Browser has to render the whole page with your example. I want that the user can choose **before** the Browser opens.

Comment: Honestly good luck and let me know if you find it. Its an interesting idea but I don't know if you can distinguish that this http request is different then another one. I would look into intents.   You could set the server to just redirect to your custom url scheme as soon as it detects its a device. This is how linkedin does it.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at it, but i would preffer a cordova Plugin or something like this :S

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `intent-filter` to your `activity` in the android manifest. Something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

   <data android:scheme="http" />
   <data android:host="www.mycoolapp.com" />
   <data android:pathPrefix="/somepath" />
</intent-filter>
```

more on what `data` you can add here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

and even more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent) on stackoverflow...

Comment: Does it works for cordova (phonegap) Applcations? I dont think, that i have access to the android manifest .

Comment: Should work fine. I typically create an app specific plugin that has the whole purpose to configure the android manifest. Check the [plugin.xml](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification) spec. You are interested in the config-file Element. Add the above snipped and you are done, cordova-cli should patch the android manifest as specified in the plugin.xml