# Is it possible to send parameter of a weblink as data to an Android app?

Tags: android, parameter-passing

Is it possible to send parameter of a weblink as data to an [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) app when clicked in Android web browser?
For example: User opens Firefox browser in Android device. Navigates to a website. Clicks a link in that website and that link opens the related app in device and sends parameter of the link as data to app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Respond To URL in Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

Comment: The solution i was looking for is actually this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser