# Capturing URLs in android

Tags: android

I am doing a security project where I have a situation like this. I have an android application, which needs to interpret any URL open request triggered from any application. Is there any intent or way that supports this in android?

My need is to capture any URL click event, check whether the URL is safe to enter. If so allow the URL to process or else show a pop up blocking the entry. To achieve this I would need to capture any URL click event from the android system

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Respond To URL in Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you mean with "URL open request".

Comment: My need is to capture any URL click event, check whether the URL is safe to enter. If so allow the URL to process or else show a pop up blocking the entry. To achieve this I would need to capture any URL click event from the android system.

Comment: @Hanno Binder he does not want the user to choose an editor for the url... He wants to handle before the choosing thingie, i think.

Comment: @eduyayo: Yes. Thats what I am looking for

Comment: What kind of "URLs" would you want to filter? HTTP? HTTPS? Non-HTTP (TCP/IP) connections?

Comment: @HannoBinder: HTTP urls only