# Not able to open tha app from URL using Custom URI scheme

Tags: android, custom-url, uri-scheme

I'm trying to open my app from URL which is send either in SMS or in Email. But it will not open my application.

Here is the code i have used in `AndroidManifest` File.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="http"
                android:scheme="m.special.scheme" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the `URL` i have passed in the email

`http://m.special.scheme/other/parameters/here`

I have also try this 
`m.special.scheme://other/parameters/here`

But this will show as a static text in email not as a URL.

Help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the "hosts" and "scheme" values swapped.. it should be:

```
<data android:host="m.special.scheme" android:scheme="http"></data>
```

Then this URL `http://m.special.scheme/other/parameters/here` should open your app...

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your Intent filter is wrong. You are providing wrong scheme and host value.

```
<activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="m.special.scheme" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```