# How to start an activity when click the webView link in a fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have a `WebView` inside a `Fragment`.

How can I start another `Activity` when I click upon a link found in the `WebView`.

Comment: You might find [this link of use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent). The trick is to use an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) to determine whether a URL matches one that your App will respond to.

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand about this intent-filter. please can u give me a complete example..

Comment: There are a lot of examples on [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=intent%20filter%20example).

Comment: There has but all are base on the activity, not with the Fragment

Comment: In this case, the Fragment is completely irrelevant. The WebView is also irrelevant. You click on the URL, Android determines that your App handles it, the associated Activity is started.

Comment: Please give me an example.. very very appreciate.