# How to intercept click on specific url and open own webclient -- Android

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-webview

I'm doing a chat, and In this chat, some messages will be links to a specific url (this url opens a document viewer in the server).

The links look, like this: `http://X.X.X.X:8080/DocumentViewer/...`

Then I have a webview activity, where I want to open this type of links.

How can "intercept"  when the user clicks on this type of links, and open my own webview and not open a "external" browser?

Comment: Are you using a ListView to display your conversation? If yes, it may be ugly, but you could set an onItemClickListener on the ListView and parse the message...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can accomplish this by creating an `intent-filter` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the URL pattern that you are interested in. The documentation for the `intent-filter`'s <[data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)> element shows how you can specify a `host` and a `scheme` ("html" in your case) to handle URLs.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/525086/4708255) answer shows an example where the developer wanted to handle youtube.com URLs. I have included the manifest snippet below for completeness:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Based on this, I think (I have not done this myself) that your intent filter should look something like:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="http://X.X.X.X:8080/DocumentViewer/" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```