# Sharing HTML to app from Chrome Android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to have my app appear in the sharing tray in the Chrome app on Android and have it share more than just the URL with my app, more specifically the entire HTML document?

I can do this on iOS by injecting some JavaScript into the current page, but I'm struggling to find an Android equivalent.

Comment: What's a "sharing tray"?

Comment: On iOS, for example, the share button on the bottom bar of the Safari app (the square with the arrow coming out the top) opens a little view that shows a list of apps you can share the current page with. You can do more or less the same thing in Chrome on Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

Comment: Alright, I understand the concept of intent filters, however I'm still struggling to find anything online about getting HTML of shared page via an intent filter.