# How to run my app in background and listen to a hyperlink click event in from other apps or browsers

Tags: android, service, systemeventlistener

User installs my app. Once installed, it runs in the background forever unless user disables the `run forever` button in my app or uninstalls my app. Now, my app need to show a popup message once a hyperlink click event is triggered from anywhere in the android device. The click event might have been triggered from default messaging apps (like user click a link provided in a message he/she has received) or from some other apps in the device like twitter and facebook.

I want to know if there is any way I could achieve this? If yes, then please suggest me how to do it.
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with Intent Filter, not by having your app run constantly in the background.

[Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

Then, you can program whatever behavior you would like to happen